# how to make url unauthorized - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Below is my `authenticate.php` which prevents guests from login into my system. But there is one route that i want to make public to my visitors/guests to be able to access. How can i exempt it from the `auth`.

The function in `authenticate.php` seems to guard my whole route at the moment.

This is the route I want to make public `Route::get('/survey/{survey}', 'SurveyController@detail_survey')->name('detail.survey');`

How do i achieve this please?

**Authenticate.php**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }

            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'SurveyController@home');
Route::get('/survey/new', 'SurveyController@new_survey')->name('new.survey');
Route::get('/survey/{survey}', 'SurveyController@detail_survey')->name('detail.survey');
```

Comment: Where are you telling Authenticate to handle the routes? Is it listed as middleware in the controller?

Comment: Are your other routes inside a Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function(){})?

If so, you could just list these routes outside of that group.

Comment: @Kat, there is nothing like that...i didn't put them in a group

Comment: @DanielGale, in my controller, i have  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In routes.php You can group you authenticated with auth middleware.
Also put non authenticated route outside from that group.

```
Route::get('visitors/guests', 'someController@guestsHandler');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
  Route::get('/survey/new', 'SurveyController@new_survey')->name('new.survey');
  Route::get('/survey/{survey}', 'SurveyController@detail_survey')->name('detail.survey');
});
```

> Note: Remove auth from global middlewares (`Kernel.php`)

Answer (score 1):

So, first, you need to spot where you register your authentication-logic. Usually you will find it in `app\controllers\middleware\kernel.php` under the Variable $middlewareGroups and the key: 'web'(providing you are using your web.php routes file as supplied by laravel).  It should, however, have a key in the variable $routeMiddleware like so:

```
['Authenticate' => yourMiddlewareClass::class],
```

Otherwise you might have registered it somewhere else, maybe trough a serviceprovider in `config\app.php`.
When you unhooked the logic, you should be able to use this structure in your `web.php` routes file:

```
//Routes outside group are not protected
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'Authenticate'], function()
{
    //All routes in the group are now protected by your middleware
    Route::get('canyouseeme', function()
    {
        echo 'Yarh';
    });
});
```